# fixed div does not update in Chrome unless at top of page or page scrolls

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

This is my first post, so I hope I am going about it the right way.

I have a div at the top of my page:

```
#data
{
    display: inline;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1999;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I then update this using a timer and the following jQuery:

```
$('#secondsToSave').html(SecondsToSave);
```

where #secondsToSave is a span within the #data div.

This works fine in Firefox, and in Chrome provided I am scrolled to the top of the page. However, as soon as I scroll down on the page a bit, the span stops updating on the screen. The counter is still working, it just seems to be the screen that is not updating. As soon as I do something, such as scrolling the page or even inspecting the element, the screen updates, but it I do nothing the screen does not update.

Any help would be most gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your element with the id "secondsToSave", the following style.

```
style="position: relative"
```

I don't know why but it fixes the issue.

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you. I don't understand it either but it works. I check it in IE and Firefox as well.