# Webkit rendering quirks for element with "position:fixed" and "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;"?

Tags: css, ipad, google-chrome, webkit, mobile-safari

Recently I encountered a rendering issue in Webkit which I suspect to be a bug with the Webkit engine. But I am not confident enough to say so. So I would like ask here and see what you think.

It'd be a bit difficult for me to describe the case in plain text, so I prepared a snippet here:
http://jsfiddle.net/2eQXa/1/

First you can see a yellow background with red border. This is not a background of the <body> tag but a <div> with id "backdrop" which has 100% width and height. By default it links to the "backdrop-no-problem" class. Also there is a horizontal list with some images. The list is surrounded by a green border. Inside the list there are some Wikipedia logos wrapped with a dotted red border.

I tested the page with the following 3 devices:
1. Chrome 21 on Windows 7
2. Mobile safari on the first generation iPad (running iOS4, I'll call it iPad1) 
3. Mobile safari on the "new" iPad (running iOS5, I'll call it iPad3)

Try clicking "right" or "left" to scroll the list. Pretty good.

To reproduce the my problem, first click on "Issue #1". This will change the backdrop div from "position:absolute" to "position:fixed". Then click "Issue #2". This will add "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;" to the element (The reason for adding this style is to ensure smooth animation on the iPad).

Now click "left/right" to scroll the list. You should see a strange behavior in all three browsers: 
The green div is scrolling properly and smoothly, but not its child elements. The child elements simply "out-sync" with the position of the scrolling parent. The movement not only looks laggy, it sometimes even stuck. And the child elements will stop at a wrong position when the scrolling animation finishes. You have to move your mouse over the picture (or tap on it in a tablet) to trigger an update to have the element re-drawn at the right place. Even Chrome shows this weirdness makes me feel that it is a Webkit issue.

Things gone worse in iPad3. In iPad3 you don't need to add "-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;" (Issue #2) to see this weird behavior. Just add "position:fixed" (Issue #1) will do. The strange thing is that this doesn't happen when you view the snippet in jsFiddle. In case you are interested I have put the source in a single file at pastebin:

http://pastebin.com/i4ARX4mD

When writing this question I saw quite a number of questions regarding backface visibility. I've checked some but none of them matches my problem.

Ideas or suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

(Post updated to fix many typos)

Comment: For me, the elements all animate, but only when my mouse is on top of them. If my mouse is removed from the element, then it starts to reset the animation.

Comment: Does it still happen in chrome stable? And does it occur in chrome canary?

Comment: did u found any solution? i have the same issue with position:fixed elements not re-rendering when updated via JS (in both chrome and ipad2). There is a post here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693931/fixed-div-does-not-update-in-chrome-unless-at-top-of-page-or-page-scrolls which says the fix works, but not for me :(